# keep input values through jquery Date picker after getting reports

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I have two input dates start date and end date. i want to keep values in these textboxes after getting reports. it works but after getting report when i click on text field then datepicker doesnot popup for start date. in if condition Datepicker shows for first item  which one comes first either start date or end date. can any one help?

```
<input runat="server" id="txtstartDate" type="text"   />
<input runat="server" id="txtFinishDate" type="text"  />
<label   id="lblHiddenStartDate" style="display:none;"></label>
<label   id="lblHiddenEndDate" style="display:none;"></label>
```

**jquery**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(function () {
            $("#txtstartDate").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
            $("#txtFinishDate").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());

        });
       if ('<%=this.IsPostBack%>'.toLowerCase() == 'true') {
            $('#txtFinishDate').datepicker().val(($("lblHiddenEndDate").val));
            $('#txtstartDate').datepicker().val(($("lblHiddenStartDate").val));
        }

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, You wanted to 'place the date values' for each input textboxes for both start and end dates.

```
 $("#txtstartDate").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

First, Not sure if its necessary to call the jquery ui datepicker twice.

```
$('#txtFinishDate').datepicker().val(($("lblHiddenEndDate").val));
```

Second, This line of code will return a JS error when you look up in your console:

> > Uncaught TypeError: this.each is not a function

Anyways, I setup a sample code as reference for your need. Hope this can be of any help for your problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sHiddenStartDate = $.trim($('#lblHiddenStartDate').text());
    var sHiddenEndDate = $.trim($('#lblHiddenEndDate').text());

    // You call datepicker then setup your value for that input box
    $('#txtstartDate').datepicker().val(sHiddenStartDate);
    $('#txtFinishDate').datepicker().val(sHiddenEndDate);
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle for further details: http://jsfiddle.net/gz066enh/

Comment: Thanks for your time. But i am sorry you didnt understand my issue. in input fields i am putting current date by default but through date picker user can select any date and after getting reports i want to keep the selected value in both input fields, that part works fine but after getting reports if i again want to select any date from date picker then i cannot getting date picker for one of fields. do you understand?

Comment: Noted. Sorry about that. If I may, Can I see your html and js source code on how you generate your reports as well? So that we can see why the [datepicker] doesn't work when you attempt to click on both input [date] fields?